# Vector Graphics in iOs?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, vector-graphics, raster

i have a vector logo that i want to include in my view. I created a png out of it and put it into an imageView. Unfortunately, the logo in the simulator then is of poor quality, even though it looks fine in Interface Builder.

Do you have a recommendation how to solve that problem? Can i embed the eps in my app?

Comment: Well, it was about the resizing. In original size, the image is fine, but when i scale it down, the quality gets worse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably convert the eps to SVG and load it in a UIWebView.